# Stopping pthread as soon as struct is freed in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a worker thread processing a queue of work items. I just implemented a second worker that process the items which were inserted in `worker1`. However, I came across some `Invalid reads` while using Valgrind.

I'm assuming this is because `struct foo` that I pass to `worker2()` is freed at some point in the main thread. Essentially `struct foo` is a struct that constantly gets updated (malloc/free), however, I'd like `worker2` to insert some missing items into `foo`.

**My question is**: is it possible for `worker2` to stop processing as soon as `struct foo` is `NULL`? and start again when `create_foo()` is called? I'm not sure what would be the best approach to insert the missing items into `foo` with a thread? Any feedback is appreciated.

```
//canonical form
//producer
void push_into_queue(char *item)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queueMutex);
    if (workQueue.full) {       // full }
        else
        {
            add_item_into_queue(item);
            pthread_cond_signal(&queueSignalPush);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
    }
}

// consumer1
void *worker1(void *arg)
{
    while (true) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueMutex);
        while (workQueue.empty)
            pthread_cond_wait(&queueSignalPush, &queueMutex);

        item = workQueue.front; // pop from queue
        add_item_into_list(item);

        pthread_cond_broadcast(&queueSignalPop);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}

pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, (void *) &worker, NULL);

// consumer2
void *worker2(void *arg)
{
    my_struct *foo = (my_struct *) arg;
    while (true) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueMutex);
        while (list.empty)
            pthread_cond_wait(&queueSignalPop, &queueMutex);

        for (i = 0; i < list.size; i++)
            insert_item_into_foo(list[i].item, foo);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&queueSignalPop);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void create_foo()
{
    my_struct *foo = calloc(10, sizeof(my_struct));
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, (void *) &worker2, foo);
}

void free_foo()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queueMutex);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
       free(foo[i].list->string);
    free(foo[i].list);
    free(foo);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
}
```

Comment: While worker2 is working on a member of foo; foo should not be freed; so you can use a semaphore for that; and workers should register themselves as waiting if they they test that foo is NULL and get woken up by the thread (foreman) which creates foo; create_should really signal existing worker threads that there is foo available to work on, and foo should have a semaphore that they can lock on to, each worker should then work on one unit of foo; upon completion release the semaphore; and try to get a semaphore again; if it can great; repeat; otherwise sleep; this may have a hiccup or two...

Comment: Sounds like an interesting approach - do you have some documentation that I could use as a reference? Also, I'm wondering if it can be done using pthreads mutex as opposed to semaphores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define any terminating condition for both `worker1` and `worker2`. I suppose that the eol of `foo` could be considered as such. This means that both workers must monitor the existence of `foo` by owning a reference to it (ie. a `foo **`).

```
void *worker2(void *arg)
{
    my_struct **foo = (my_struct **) arg;
    while(true) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueMutex);
        while (list.empty)
            pthread_cond_wait(&queueSignalPop, &queueMutex);
        if (NULL == *foo) 
            break;
        for (i = 0; i < list.size; i++)
            insert_item_into_foo(list[i].item, *foo);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&queueSignalPop);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
    }
    free(foo);
    return NULL;
}

void create_foo()
{
    my_struct *foo = calloc(10, sizeof(my_struct ));
    my_struct **foo_ptr = malloc(1, sizeof(my_struct *));
    *foo_ptr = foo;
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, (void *) &worker2, foo_ptr);
   // more work with foo
}
```

Note that somehow `foo` must be assigned to a different variable so as to be reachable in `free_foo` (your code supposes this fact without explicitely showing it - hence my comment at the end of `create_foo`).

With the code above, each instance of `worker2` owns a pointer to rely on for its whole lifetime, and which it must take care of before exiting.

### Update:

Perhaps a better solution consists in passing a struct to `thread2`, which contains the `foo` pointer, as well as a flag indicating if that pointer is still valid. You may add any other piece of information needed by the thread in the struct ad lib.

```
struct th2_data {
    enum {RUNNING, TERMINATING} state;
    my_struct *foo;
};
```

Then allocate a instance of that struct, initialize it as `{RUNNING, foo}`, and pass it to `thread2`. Keep a copy of its address somewhere to be able to signal the `TERMINATING` state to `thread2`. Indeed, as you asked in your comments, you would have to replace the `if (NULL == *foo)` test in thread2 by `if (foo.state == TERMINATING)`.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question, do I need to `**foo_ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(my_struct *))` or it has to be the same size as `*foo` (**foo_ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(my_struct *)))?

Comment: this is just a single pointer, not an array of 10 entries: notice how you never need to use the subscript operator `[]` with it in the code. In fact, I thought about making it a struct, so that you could store in there any other value you would need to pass to the threads; that's how I usually do.

Comment: Got it. One more question. If `foo` is an array of pointers to structures, can I define `*foo_ptr` as: `*foo_ptr = foo[2];` and pass `foo_ptr` in `pthread_create`? 

Could that cause an issue when I `free_foo()`? (I updated free_foo() for reference)

Comment: `foo[2]` is not a pointer, it's a plain foo value, so you cannot do that assignment. However, you could do `*foo_ptr = foo + 2;` to have it hold a pointer to the second structure.

Comment: Thanks for the update. My question is: wouldn't the `RUNNING`, `TERMINATING` flags be the same as checking `if (NULL == *foo)` considering that thread2 has the mutex?

Comment: you are correct, I updated my answer to include that point, as well as removing my suspicion of a race condition, since the mutex excludes it (sorry about that).

Answer (score 1):

Make foo global and add some pointer check in the loop.
Next time when you call create_foo, it will restart the thread.

```
my_struct *foo = NULL;
```

// consumer2
void *worker2(void *arg)
{

`while (true) {
    if ( fool == NULL )
        return;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queueMutex);
    while (list.empty)
        pthread_cond_wait(&queueSignalPop, &queueMutex);

    for (i = 0; i < list.size; i++)
        insert_item_into_foo(list[i].item, foo);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&queueSignalPop);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
}
return NULL;`

}